# In TS generics, why T != { foo: T['foo'] } & Omit<T, 'foo'>?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have this code:

```
interface Base {
  id: string
}

interface Foo<T extends Base> {
    id: T['id'],
    rest: Omit<T, 'id'>
    check: (props: T) => void
}

function main <P extends Base>({ id, rest, check }: Foo<P>): void {
  check({
      id,
      ...rest
  })
}
```

And TS (v4.7.2) says that:

```
Argument of type '{ id: P["id"]; } & Omit<P, "id">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'.
  '{ id: P["id"]; } & Omit<P, "id">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.(2345)
```

Each time when I had this error it was correct, but in this case, I can't understand the reason.

For me, this error sounds like `(x - 1 + 1) != x`.

Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

Comment: In all those questions that I checked, the type of replaced property was not identical. But in this case, the type of "id" is the same

Comment: I should be able to answer that, but I can't, I'm just not far enough along in my TS. I've removed what may well have been an incorrect comment above, but I suggest seriously studying the previous answers on this, I strongly suspect they do address the above. Good luck with it!

Comment: Hm, it seems it's a known bug in TS: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43366

Comment: And [a search](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+43366+is%3Aanswer) doesn't turn up an answer referencing that issue. Yeah, that issue does look similar to what you're seeing above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's [a known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43366) in TS